# Using Shell Commands to Manipulate File Paths for Use as Arguments to Another Program

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, find

I can use `find` like this to find a list of files:

```
find -type f -path "./src*" -name "*.php"`
```

For example:

```
./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/UUID.php
./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/Mapper.php
```

What I need to do, is read the filename:

```
./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/Mapper/UUID.php
```

And use it to generate PHPUnit test skeletons based on information contained in the path:

```
Superuseradmin\Model\Mapper\UUID  
./test/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/UUIDTest.php
```

So that I can run this command for each one:

```
phpunit-skelgen.phar --test -- Superuseradmin\Model\Mapper\MyMapper \
./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/MyMapper.php \
./test/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/MyMapperTest.php
```

Comment: Unfortunately your example is inconsistent: "For example ./src/Superuseradmin/Model/UUID.php"; "file from find command: ./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/UUID.php".

Comment: @HaukeLaging have fixed that

Comment: It's still inconsistent. In the explanation it's `UUID`, in the call example `MyMapper`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick attempt:

```
for i in `find -type f -path "./src*" -name "*.php"`; do echo phpunit-skelgen.phar --test -- `echo $i | sed -e 's!./src/!!' | sed -e 's/.php//' | sed -e 's/\\//\\\/g'` $i `echo $i | sed -e 's!./src/!./test/!' | sed -e 's/.php/Test.php/'`;done
```

Given the following directory structure:

```
./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/MyMapper.php
./src/Superuseradmin/Model/UUID.php
```

It should output:

```
phpunit-skelgen.phar --test -- Superuseradmin\Model\Mapper\MyMapper ./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/MyMapper.php ./test/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/MyMapperTest.php
phpunit-skelgen.phar --test -- Superuseradmin\Model\UUID ./src/Superuseradmin/Model/UUID.php ./test/Superuseradmin/Model/UUIDTest.php
```

You can then save this to a script, check it and run. Watch out for spaces in file names. They will cause trouble.

Comment: Why should one ever use a pipeline of several `sed` instances immediately after one another instead of using one `sed` instance with several `-e` parameters? Furthermore one such line is an understanding nightmare. Compute values, assign them to variables, run commands with the variables (instead of the computing expressions).

Comment: Ended up using a variation of this, thanks.

`for i in \`find -type f -path "./src*" -name "*.php"\`; do mkdir -p \`dirname $(echo $i | sed -e 's!./src/\([[:alnum:]]*\)!./test/\1Test!')\`; phpunit-skelgen.phar --bootstrap test/Bootstrap.php --test -- \`echo $i | sed -e 's!./src/!!' -e 's/.php//' -e 's!\/!\\\\!g'\` $i \`echo $i | sed -e 's/.php/Test/' -e 's!./src/\([[:alnum:]]*\)!\1Test!' -e 's!\/!\\\\!g'\` \`echo $i | sed -e 's!./src/\([[:alnum:]]*\)!./test/\1Test!' -e 's/.php/Test.php/'\`;done`

Answer (score 0):

You create a shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

find_path="./src/Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/UUID.php"
# find_path="$1"
class="${find_path#./src/}" # Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/UUID.php
class="${class%.php}" # Superuseradmin/Model/Mapper/UUID
class="${class//\//\\}" # Superuseradmin\Model\Mapper\UUID
classhead="${class%\\*}" # Superuseradmin\Model\Mapper
classtail="${class#"$classhead"}" # \UUID
class="${classhead}${classtail}" # Superuseradmin\Model\Mapper\UUID
# echo "class: '${class}'"

testfile="./test${find_path#./src}"
testfile="${testfile%.php}Test.php"
# echo "testfile: '${testfile}'"

echo phpunit-skelgen.phar --test -- "$class" "$find_path" "$testfile"
```

And make `find` call this script:

```
find -type f -path "./src*" -name "*.php" -exec /my/script.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
cd src
for i in $(find . -type f -name '*.php'); do
 SRC=$i
 DST="../test/$(dirname $i)/$(basename $i php)Test.php"
 echo "copy $SRC to $DST"
 #cp $SRC $DST
done
```

Comment: `for i in ...; SRC=$i` instead of `for SRC in...`? Using a mix of two variables with the same content afterwards...?

Comment: I'm giving an idea to illustrate what's possible.Up to you to figure out the rest

Comment: You give an idea what is bad coding. Up to the others to correct that. I did that (at least point it out). This bad coding has nothing to do with "what's possible" with respect to the problem to be solved.

Comment: Yeah, your code is the best anyway. ;-)